# Access 3D tensor (image) using a 2d tensor of indices

Tags: python, pytorch

With the following 3D tensor representing an image 
`img.shape=[H,W,F]`
And a tensor representing the indices to that img 
`indices.shape=[N,2]`
E.g. if 
`indices = [[0,1],[5,3],...]]`
I would like to create a new tensor of shape `new.shape=[N,F]` where 
`new[k] == img[indices[k][0],indices[k][1]]`
Currently to solve this I flatten both tensors:

```
    idx_flattened = idx_flattened [:,0] * (idx_flattened [:,1].max()+1) + idx_flattened[:,1]
    img = img .reshape(-1,F)
    new = img[idx_flattened ]
```

But I'm certain there is a better way:)

Here's a full minimal example:

```
img = torch.arange(8*10*3).reshape(8,10,3)
indices = torch.tensor([[0,0],[3,0],[1,2]])
new = img[indices] <- This does not work
new = [[  0,   1,   2],[ 90,  91,  92],[ 36,  37,  38]]
```

Ideas?

Comment: Please provide minimum reproducible example with the expected output.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, is that better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slicing would work

```
img[indices[:,0], indices[:,1]]
tensor([[ 0,  1,  2],
        [90, 91, 92],
        [36, 37, 38]])
```